# Can you navigate from a tabbedpage to a contentpage with the default constructor being changed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbedpage that I am wanting to navigate to a content page that it is taking user input and displaying in binding context on the xaml page.

The issue I am running into is if i try to parse the object of the database using:

```
public Personalize(User user)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new PersonalizeViewModel(user);
}
```

I am getting an error that "missing default constructor".

When I add a second default construction like below the error goes away but no data is pulled from the user input from the database:

```
public Personalize()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public Personalize(User user)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new PersonalizeViewModel(user);
}
```

My mainpage has the login/signup components and is navigating to the TabbedPage. When I navigate it the Personalize page it displays the data but whenever through navigating through the TabbedPage it doesn't show the data from the database.

Comment: You can’t use a constructor parameter when navigating this way.  Consider setting the user as a property on the App object so it will be available throughout the app

Comment: @Reaper ,good job!  You can post the working example as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is what @Jason mentioned above. Is to set the user property on the App object.

**App.Xaml**

```
public static User LoggedInUser { get; set; }
```

**ViewModel.PersonalizeViewModel**

```
public PersonalizeViewModel()
{
    _user = App.LoggedInUser;
    Username = _user.username;
    Email = _user.email;
    Password = _user.password;
    Shopping = _user.Shopping;
    Milk = _user.Milk;
    Loathes = _user.Loathes;
    Meat = _user.Meat;
    Fish = _user.Fish;
    Eggs = _user.Eggs;
    Vegetables = _user.Vegetables;
    Fruit = _user.Fruit;
}
```

**View.Personalize.xaml.cs**

```
public PersonalizeViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public Personalize()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new PersonalizeViewModel();
}
```

**View.Personalize.xaml**

```
<Label Text="{Binding Username}" />

<Label Text="Email:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Email}" />

<Label Text="Meat:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Meat}" />

<Label Text="Fish:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Fish}" />

<Label Text="Shopping frequency:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Shopping}" />

<Label Text="Milk:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Milk}" />

<Label Text="Loathes:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Loathes}" />

<Label Text="Eggs:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Eggs}" />

<Label Text="Vegetables:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Vegetables}" />

<Label Text="Fruit:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Fruit}" />

<Label Text="Loathes:" />
<Label Text="{Binding Loathes}" />
```